# How to get "disconnecting" event Nest SocketIO

Tags: javascript, socket.io, nestjs

I have a problem to get all room that socket client currently in when this client disconnect, by using

```
async handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
    console.log(client.rooms) // result is {}
}
```

but Nest-SocketIO only return list rooms as {}.
As I known, in socketIO we can use:

```
socket.on("disconnecting", ()=>{
console.log(socket.rooms // return all room current
}
```

How can I use this features in NestJS-SOcketIO ?
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by attaching event handler on connection.

```
  handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]) {
    this.logger.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
    client.on('disconnecting', (reason) => {
      this.logger.log(`DISCONNECTING: ${Array.from(client.rooms)}`); // Set { ... }
    });
  }
```